# android sqlite foreign key not working

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite

i'm trying to create a relationship between 2 tables but the FK is not populating. it is remaining null. below is my code

```
 public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
// Database Name
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "LocalRugbyDB.db";

//table names
public static final String TABLE_PLAYER_INFO = "PLAYER_Local";
public static final String TABLE_TEAM_INFO = "TEAM_local";

//add fields to player table
public static final String KEY_PLAYER_ID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_FNAME = "first_name";
public static final String KEY_LNAME = "last_name";
public static final String KEY_AGE = "age";
public static final String KEY_HEIGHT = "height";
public static final String KEY_WEIGHT = "weight";
public static final String KEY_POSITION = "position";
public static final String KEY_TEAM = "team";
public static final String TEAM_ID = "team_id";

// add field to team table
public static final String KEY_TEAM_ID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_TEAMNAME = "team_name";

public MySQLiteHelper(Context context, String name,
        CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION); 
    Log.i("onCreateMaybe", "Created");
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // SQL statement to create book table
    String CREATE_PLAYER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PLAYER_INFO + "( "
            + KEY_PLAYER_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + KEY_FNAME + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_LNAME + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_POSITION + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_HEIGHT + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_AGE + " TEXT," 
            + KEY_WEIGHT + " TEXT," 
            + KEY_TEAM + " TEXT,"
            + TEAM_ID + " integer,"
            + " FOREIGN KEY ("+TEAM_ID+") REFERENCES "+TABLE_TEAM_INFO+" ("+KEY_TEAM_ID+"));";


    String CREATE_TEAM_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_TEAM_INFO + "( "
            + KEY_TEAM_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + KEY_TEAMNAME + " TEXT" + ");";

    // create books table
    db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;");
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TEAM_TABLE);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_PLAYER_TABLE);

}
```

here you can see that the FK column (team_id) is not being populated. im not getting any error and have been trying to fix this for hours.[image]

Comment: How are you inserting the data?  When I do this sort of thing, I first create the "foreign" row (team) and, using the FK generated, then insert the row in the dependent table (player).  There might be slicker ways of doing this, but this works.  Also, you might add some qualifiers to prevent the FK from being null.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Foreign keys are a mechnism to ensure that the database stays consistent; they do *not* automatically look up values from other tables.

You still have to do all the work yourself.
The only difference is that the database will prevent you from making inconsistent changes.

---

Your database is not properly normalized; the team name is duplicated in all player records.
Just drop KEY_TEAM from the player table.

To insert a new player with the correct team ID, you would use code like this:

```java
long lookupOrCreateTeamID(String name) {
    Cursor c = db.query(TABLE_TEAM_INFO, new String[] { KEY_TEAM_ID },
                        KEY_TEAMNAME + " = ?", new String[] { name },
                        null, null, null);
    if (c.moveToFirst())
        return c.getLong(0);
    else {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_TEAMNAME, name);
        return db.insert(TABLE_TEAM_INFO, null, cv);
    }
}

long createPlayer(String firstName, ..., String teamName) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_FNAME, firstName);
    ...
    cv.put(TEAM_ID, lookupOrCreateTeamID(teamName));
    return db.insert(TABLE_PLAYER_INFO, null, cv);
}
```

---

Please note that the `PRAGMA foreign_keys` must be executed again for *every* connection that opens the database.
So you should not do this in `onCreate` but in [onConfigure](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onConfigure%28android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase%29) (if you're using API level 16):

```java
@Override
public void onConfigure(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabled(true);
}
```